# On p-group of maximal class

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be a $p$-group of order $p^{4}$ and exponent $p$. I want to prove that if $G$ has no nontrivial direct factors then it is of maximal class.

My try:
Let $H$ be a proper nonabelian subgroup of $G$, then $|H|=p^{3}$. Now, let $x\in C_G(H)$. If $x\notin H$ then $G=\langle x\rangle\cdot H$, a contradiction. So, $C_{G}(H)<H$.

Did I miss something? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would be nice if you also considered the case when any subgroup of $G$ of the index $p$ is abelian.

Comment: To be clear: you are assuming that $G$ has a proper nonabelian subgroup; you must either establish this, or you must consider the possibility that all proper subgroups of $G$ are abelian.